# Import existing Database into Neo4j Desktop Application (v1.1.9)

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I created a Neo4j database using `neo4j-admin.bat import` command on Windows 10.

After that, I see the database being successfully created under

```
E:\neo4jDatabases\database-6c03e895-692f-4f45-90e4-dc29e0f5bfeb\
    installation-3.4.1\data\databases\graph2.db
```

How can I access/work with this database in Neo4j Desktop now? I am looking for a way to add this newly created db to my project but I only see options for

(a) Creating a local Graph and
(b) Connecting to a Remote Graph.

I tried to connect to a local database but I haven't set username/password for graph2.db during import so this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a local database.

Then open the folder of the database and copy your `graph.db` folder inside the neo4j folder `data/databases` (important: the name of th folder must be `graph.db`, not `graph2.db`).

For your information the login/password are not stored inside the `graph.db`.